# DNA genome string reconstruction from k-mer

Tags: assembly, algorithms, k-mer, homework

I have the following quiz question, but the Pattern1 for both `(ACC|ATA)` and `(CGA|ACT)` are unique (just grep for `ACC` and `CGA`), which means it might be difficult to find the starting pattern for the DNA genome string in the following case. Do I need something like [GapReduce algorithm](https://sci-hub.ee/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8247239) ?

Quiz : There is a single (linear) string with the following (3,1)-mer composition. Find it.

```
(ACC|ATA) (ACT|ATT) (ATA|TGA) (ATT|TGA) (CAC|GAT) (CCG|TAC) (CGA|ACT)

(CTG|AGC) (CTG|TTC) (GAA|CTT) (GAT|CTG) (GAT|CTG) (TAC|GAT) (TCT|AAG)

(TGA|GCT) (TGA|TCT) (TTC|GAA)
```

[image: k-d mer]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As shown in the picture in the question, just align the (k, d)-mers vertically without the help of assembler software, then compare whether they conflict with each other vertically. Maybe the software to do such comparison uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm